# what does this statement (line, str) = str.split("\n", 1) mean?

Tags: python, string, iterable

I am familiar with the `split` function and I would use it as such:

```
str = "Line1-abcdef \nLine2-abc \nLine4-abcd"
print str.split( )
```

The above would return this:

```
['Line1-abcdef', 'Line2-abc', 'Line4-abcd']
```

Simple and easy. However, I came across a piece of code that has this statement:

```
(line, str) = str.split("\n", 1)
```

There are two things that I dont understand here:

1. The second parameter of `split` and what that does. I looked [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm) and it says the number of lines made. What does that mean?
2. `split` returns an iterable vector. Why is it being assigned to `(line, str)`? What does `(line, str)` mean here?

Comment: If you are curious, why don't you **try** it?

Comment: Read the documentation you pointed out more carefully, specially the example, you will understand.

Comment: See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) for how split works.

Comment: @Bakuriu thanks could you put that as an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second argument `maxsplit=1` means *stop splitting after you meet the separator `\n` once*.

Therefore you have only two parts, your line and the rest of the string.

---

For example:

```
str = 'This is one line\nThis is a second line\nThis is a third line'
(line, str) = str.split('\n', 1)
print(line)
# 'This is one line'
print(str)
# 'This is a second line\nThis is a third line'
```

Comment: It's quite unfortunate that in python2 the maxsplit argument cannot be passed by keyword. This is fixed in python3 where you *can* write `str.split('\n', maxsplit=1)` and makes the code much more self documenting.

Answer (score 0):

Testing with a basic string, `how do you do ?`.
`line` will get the first element of the split, and `str` will get the rest (as we only split once)